# Partition of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm studyng integral calculus of several variables, we started with the definition of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$, its "volume" and what is a partition of it, which is usually constructed as follows:

> Definition $1$. Let $R = [a_1, b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n, b_n]$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for each $1\leq i\leq n$, let $P_i$ be a partition of $[a_i, b_i]$, we call to the set $\mathcal{P}= P_1\times \cdots\times P_n$ a partition of $R$.

In order to generalize the notion of "partition" of a rectangle, I tried to define a "new" type of partition. So I made the following definitions

> Definition $2$. Let $R$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we say that $R$ is a rectangle if $R=\emptyset$ or $$R = \prod_{i=1}^{n} [a_i, b_i]$$ where $a_i, b_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. If $R = \emptyset$ we define $vol(R) =0$, otherwise we define $$vol(R) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (b_i-a_i)$$

> Definition $3$. Let $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a finite subset of rectangles contained in $R$, we say that $\mathcal{Q}$ is a partition of $R$ if $$vol(R) = \sum_{B\in \mathcal{Q}} vol(B)$$

after this, I tried to prove a statement that looks intuitive to me:

> Theorem 1. Let $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a finite subset of rectangles contained in $R$, $\mathcal{Q}$ is a partition (in the sense of definition 3) of $R$ if and only if $R = \bigcup \mathcal{Q}$ and $vol(A\cap B) = 0$ for all $A,B\in\mathcal{Q}$ with $A\not=B$.

My question is: How can I prove that statement? I tried it via induction on the number of rectangles in $\mathcal{Q}$ but I didn't know how to continue the proof.

Comment: Does Definition 3 allow $Q$ to have overlapping rectangles?

Comment: @VTand Well, Definition 3 doesn't say anything about if the rectangles are overlapping or not, that is the purpose of Theorem 1, it says that if $\mathcal{Q}$ is a partition, then the are not overlapping rectangles.

Comment: Then, unless I misunderstand your definitions, would $R = [1, 3], Q = \{[1.1, 2.1], [1.2, 2.2]\}$ be a counter example for the theorem?

Comment: The problem is exactly that your definition doesn't say anything about $Q$ overlapping. You can create such a $Q$ simply by choosing rectangles at random - not caring about whether they overlap, until the sum of their volumes is $\ge \text{vol}(R)$. Then take the last added rectangle and shrink one of its dimensions until the sum is actually equal to the volume of $R$. There is no reason at all for $\bigcup Q$ to be $R$.